# Jquery Scrolling to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need some proper scrolling solution for the tabs in bottom. the working code can be view at  :[this link](http://design.online-folio.com/xhtml/sc/index.html)

check the footer links of web design etc. the jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.locations div').hide();
    $('#footer ul.left li a').click(function() {
        $('#footer ul.left li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.locations div').hide("normal");
        $(currentTab).show("normal");
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(document).height()
        }, "normal");
        return false;
    });    
});​
```

the problem is: when clicked on a link the window scroll down properly, but when another link is clicked then there is a small jerk in the page. also on clicking the same link again. the scroll goes up but the contents are not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I only see the problem when clicking the same link a second time. Try checking if the link's been clicked by checking if it has your class 'active'. If it's already been clicked, don't reload anything:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.locations div').hide();
  $('#footer ul.left li a').click(function(){
   if (!$(this).hasClass('active')){  //If it HASN'T been clicked yet
    $('#footer ul.left li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.locations div').hide("normal");
    $(currentTab).show("normal");
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "normal");
    return false;
   }
 }); 
});
```

see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UxPut/)

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler code can be broken down to the following steps

1. remove class from all li's
2. add class to clicked li.
3. hide all info divs.
4. show clicked li's info div.

As you can see, you are showing the clicked li's info div at ALL times. Which is why you are having the second problem (clicking same link doesnt hide the info).

Regarding the first problem, if we remove the animation to scroll to document bottom, the jerk is no more there. You could choose to implement the scroll to bottom only if an info div is not present, ie there is no li with the class 'active'.

Pseudo code for the click handler

```
find li with class active.
- if not found
  - add class to current li. show current li's info div. scroll to bottom.
- if found,
  - check whether li is same as the li we clicked on.
    - if yes,
      - hide the current li's info div. exit the function.
    - if no,
      - hide the info div for the currently active li.
      - show the info div for the li clicked on.
```

If you need js code for this, ask away in the comments.